# SMTP Time out error - Send email from localhost

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I tried to send email using `Google SMTP` from `localhost`, but I keep getting the `SMTP time out.` error.
This is my config:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'tls://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'username' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'xxxxxsecret',
            'log' => true,
            'tls' => true,
            'domain' => 'localhost',
        ],
    ],
```

I'm running my app on Wampp server.

Please help me, thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Using mailtrap, you can test this locally. If this works, then most likely the configuration is incorrect or the email isn't being sent through google mail.

https://mailtrap.io - create account and use for free.

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
        'port' => 2525,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
        'password' => 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

You can also change the port from 587 to 465 and check. Allow Google to trust your local email server.